# Apps Script - Need Advice with Optimization or Maximum Runtime Bypass

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, runtimeexception

I'm trying to run a script in Apps Script, but the problem is that with my current code it would take up to 6 hours to complete the function/execution. With the one request maximum runtime of 6 minutes and daily runtime limit of 1 hour it would take me 6 days do get the needed data.

My 3 questions would be:

1. Is there any way I can optimize my code for it to have a quicker execution/runtime?
2. Is there a way to bypass the single maximum runtime of 6 minutes?
3. If there is a way to bypass the 6 minutes, is there a way to bypass the daily maximum runtime of 1 hour?

The code I'm running is the following:

```
function scrapeBuff163() {

  var startIndex = 33858;
  var endIndex = 60000;
  var response;

  for(var i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/sell_order?game=csgo&goods_id="+i,   
          {muteHttpExceptions: true });

      if(response.getContentText().length >= 1500){
        spliceAndInsert(response);
      }
  }
}

function spliceAndInsert(response){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Buff163");
  var marketHashSubLen = 21;
  var goodsIdSubLen = 12;
  var idStart = response.getContentText().search('"goods_id"');
  var goodsId = response.getContentText().slice(idStart,idStart+17).substring(goodsIdSubLen);

  var marketHashStart = response.getContentText().search('"market_hash_name"');
  let marketHashName = response.getContentText().slice(marketHashStart,marketHashStart+100).substring(marketHashSubLen);
  marketHashName = marketHashName.substring(0, marketHashName.search('"'));

  sheet.appendRow([goodsId, marketHashName]);
}
```

Thank you in advance! :D

p.s. I know my code isn't using the best practices.

Comment: Hey @Tedinoz,

Firstly, thank you for the fast reply. I’ll answer why the full execution would take 6 days first. The daily runtime limit is 1 hour. I have about 26000 loops to run and one loop takes on avarage 0,8 seconds. 26000*0,8/60/60 which comes out to 5,8 hours so with the daily limitation it would take 6 days…..

Comment: ……
Secondly, why am I doing this? 
1. To map the on site ID’s (goods_id) with the respective skin. So finding the skins ID in the future for a request would be faster and less painful. Maybe even automated at some point in same way. 
2. My plan was too run the requests daily with another sites requests and compare the prices to find the best deals or the highest profit margin. (Haven’t started on the other sites requests yet)